# Anosov flow on the 2-sphere

Tags: reference-request, ds.dynamical-systems, anosov-systems

Is there a simple proof that there is no Anosov flow on $S^2$? Where can I find it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The usual definition of Anosov flow requires three invariant sub-bundles, so I guess you are actually asking about the 3-sphere?

Plante and Thurston have proved in

*Plante, J. F.; Thurston, W. P.*, [**Anosov flows and the fundamental group**](https://doi.org/10.1016/0040-9383(72)90002-X), Topology 11, 147-150 (1972). [ZBL0246.58014](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0246.58014).

that if a manifold admits a codimension 1 Anosov flow, then its fundamental group has exponential growth.

Comment: You're right! What about Anosov diffeomorphisms?

Comment: The only (orientable) surface admitting an Anosov diffeomorphism is the torus. One way to see this is using the Euler characteristic: the unstable foliation has no closed leaf (otherwise the diffeomorphism would be expanding on the closed leaf), and the only surface admitting such a foliation is the torus.

Comment: @Uagi - If you admit "poles" (once-pronged singularities of the foliations) then you can obtain pseudo-Anosov homoemorphisms.  This is why "pseudo-Anosov braids" can exist.